# Do IID experiments maximize Fisher information?

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, references, fisher-information, iid

Let $x$ and $y$ be random variables whose probabilities depend on an unknown parameter $\theta$. I am specifically interested in the case that both $x$ and $y$ are Bernoulli, but the question below can also be asked in general. Assuming sufficient regularity, the Fisher information of a set $X$ of random variables about $\theta$ is given by the expression:

$
\mathcal{I}_X(\theta)= -E\left[\left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log f(X;\theta)\,\right|\theta\right]\enspace ,
$

where $f(X;\theta)$ is the probability density of $X$ conditional on $\theta$.

If $x$ and $y$ are independent, then:

$\mathcal{I}_{x,y}(\theta)= \mathcal{I}_{x}(\theta)+\mathcal{I}_{y}(\theta)\enspace .$

> **Question:** Is it always true (even when $x$ and $y$ are dependent) that $\mathcal{I}_{x,y}(\theta)\leq \mathcal{I}_{x}(\theta)+\mathcal{I}_{y}(\theta)$?

My intuition from Shannon information tells me that surely this is so- if you have a coin, and you toss it once, your optimal strategy for the second toss is surely just to toss it again. But I've been unable to find a proof for this, and the analysis gets very complicated very fast when I try to prove this "subadditivity" property analytically.

> **Question:** Do you have a reference for this property?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Stam's proof](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0019995859903481/1-s2.0-S0019995859903481-main.pdf?_tid=8a6f6744-105e-11e5-baa6-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1434043574_e57113cdcad9e5a8f525b9a0c6af4e2f) which is the original proof of Fisher information sub-addivity, and [maybe on this one too](http://mate.unipv.it/toscani/publi/Young-last.pdf) which uses a generalized result. [This paper](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAAahUKEwjR1KWyl4jGAhUJXRQKHY49AIM&url=http%3A%2F%2Frepository.tudelft.nl%2Fassets%2Fuuid%3A111d8157-3ace-4ddf-8934-74ee08269b89%2F13635285.PDF&ei=oMd5VdGEAYm6UY77gJgI&usg=AFQjCNHq7S8zIwQgAfU1cKC_UThyMCEIoQ&sig2=bcV-6KuGo6OMc2-3vkKTKg&bvm=bv.95277229,d.ZGU) contains a proof of a related result. Hope it helps!

-- edit
You're right, this is another property, sorry for being misleading.
According to my PhD advisor, it does not hold; [sometimes super-additivity](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002212369190155X), ([other inequalities](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0604028.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks! Is this the correct subadditivity property though? It looks to me like subadditivity with respect to something else- namely $\mathcal{I}_{T(x,y)}\leq \mathcal{I}_{x,y}$ for any function T, where x,y are iid (equation 1.5 in Stam). Have I missed something?

Comment: I've skimmed through all three references you gave now, and can't find the statement of subadditivity in the sense that I need it- could you point me to it? Note in particular that a Bernoulli random variable does not have a continuous probability density function (of course); the references seem to all be working with condituous pdfs.

Comment: Thank you for this. I now see that the opposite sometimes holds (because the joint holds more information than the sum of the marginals)- but I am still pretty sure that we have subadditivity in the Bernoulli case. Thinking further...